# Understanding an SFINAE example

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae

I have difficulties to understand SFINAE. For example, I do not understand why the following code does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// first implementation
template< size_t M, std::enable_if<M==1,size_t>::type = 0>
int foo()
{
  return 1;
}

// second implementation
template< size_t M, std::enable_if<M!=1,size_t>::type = 0>
float foo()
{
  return 1.0f;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << foo<1>() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I have expected the following behavior: `foo<1>` uses the first implementation since `std::enable_if < M==1,size_t>::type = 0>` causes no substitution error while `std::enable_if < M!=1,size_t>::type = 0>` does.

Does anyone see the mistake in my argumentation?

Comment: What's the error message? Try add `typename` before `std::enable_if...`.

Comment: Your argumentation is OK but your code is wrong :-) As mentioned from songyuanyao `typename` is missing.

Comment: The answer really depends on the error message here. For standard C++, yes, only `typename` needs to be added, but there's also a big commonly used not fully conforming compiler out there that has some issues with template overloads. If the error comes from that particular compiler, the answer would be very different.

Comment: Compile with `typename` added: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92b71654ed9f0f42).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you must add `typename` before `std::enable_if` because `::type` is a [dependent type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name):

```
template< size_t M, typename std::enable_if<M==1,size_t>::type = 0>
int foo()
{
  return 1;
}
```

In C++14, you may use `std::enable_if_t`, which is an alias to `std::enable_if<...>::type`, and "embeds" the additional `typename`:

```
template< size_t M, std::enable_if_t<M==1,size_t> = 0>
int foo()
{
  return 1;
}
```